# ComponentDidUpdate doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to render dynamically a collection of component using `componentDidUpdate`.
This is my scenario:

```
var index = 0;

class myComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      componentList: [<ComponentToRender key={index} id={index} />]
    };

    this.addPeriodHandler = this.addPeriodHandler.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidUpdate = () => {
    var container = document.getElementById("container");
    this.state.componentList.length !== 0
      ? ReactDOM.render(this.state.componentList, container)
      : ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(container);
  };

  addHandler = () => {
    var array = this.state.componentList;
    index++;
    array.push(<ComponentToRender key={index} id={index} />);
    this.setState = {
      componentList: array
    };
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="Wrapper">
        <button id="addPeriod" onClick={this.addHandler}>
          Add Component
        </button>
        <div id="container" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The problem is that `componentDidUpdate` work only one time, but it should work every time that component's state change. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: #1 rule of the react club is: never mutate state/props.

Comment: Where do "the components to render" come from?

Comment: It's a component that I import from another folder

Comment: But what does it contain? Does it render any data?

Comment: It contain four input fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not how to use react. With `ReactDOM.render()` you are creating an entirely new component tree. Usually you only do that once to initially render your app. Everything else will be rendered by the `render()` functions of your components. If you do it with `ReactDOM.render()` you are basically throwing away everything react has already rendered every time you update your data and recreate it from scratch when in reality you may only need to add a single node somewhere.

Also what you actually store in the component state should be plain data and not components. Then use this data to render your components in the `render()` function.

Example for a valid use case:

```
class MyComponent extends Component{
        state = {
            periods: []
        };

        handleAddPeriod = () => {
            this.setState(oldState => ({
                periods: [
                    ...oldState.periods,
                    {/*new period data here*/}
                ],
            });
        };

        render() {
            return (
                <div id="Wrapper">                                 
                    <button id="addPeriod" onClick={this.handleAddPeriod}>
                        Add Component
                    </button>
                    <div id="container">
                        {periods.map((period, index) => (
                            <ComponentToRender id={index} key={index}>
                                {/* render period data here */}
                            </ComponentToRender>
                        ))}
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Also you should not work with global variables like you did with `index`. If you have data that changes during using your application this is an indicator that is should be component state.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
addHandler = () =>{
    var array = this.state.componentList.slice();
    index++;
    array.push(<ComponentToRender key={index} id={index}/>);
    this.setState=({
        componentList: array
    });
}
```

if that works, this is an issue with the state holding an Array reference that isn't changing. When you're calling `setState` even though you've added to the Array, it still sees the same reference because `push` doesn't create a new Array. You might be able to get by using the same array if you also implement `shouldComponentUpdate` and check the array length of the new state in there to see if it's changed.